# "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" when moving itertools product inside function

Tags: python, function, python-itertools

I'm trying to move a usage of `itertools.product` inside a function. When I try to do this, I am presented with the following error message and I'm not sure why:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The code is as follows. In the `main` function, you can see the algorithm used outside the function and then you can see the algorithm used when packaged in the function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import itertools

def main():

    elements_specification = [[10, 20], [30, 40], [50, 60]]

    lists = [list(list_generated) for index, element_specification in enumerate(elements_specification) for list_generated in itertools.product(*elements_specification[:index + 1])]

    for list_configuration in lists:
        print(list_configuration)

    print("---")

    for list_configuration in list_element_combinations_variadic(
        [[10, 20], [30, 40], [50, 60]]
    ):
        print(list_configuration)

def list_element_combinations_variadic(
    elements_specification
    ):
    """
    This function accepts a specification of lists of elements for each place in
    lists in the form of a list, the elements of which are lists of possible
    elements and returns a list of lists corresponding to the combinations of
    elements of the specification with varying numbers of elements.

    For example, the list elements specification [[10, 20], [30, 40], [50, 60]]
    yields the following lists:

    [10]
    [20]
    [10, 30]
    [10, 40]
    [20, 30]
    [20, 40]
    [10, 30, 50]
    [10, 30, 60]
    [10, 40, 50]
    [10, 40, 60]
    [20, 30, 50]
    [20, 30, 60]
    [20, 40, 50]
    [20, 40, 60]
    """
    lists = [list(list_generated) for index, elements_specification in enumerate(elements_specification) for list_generated in itertools.product(*elements_specification[:index + 1])]
    return lists

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You mean move `itertools.product` inside a list-comprehension?

Comment: It would help if you told us which line of code is causing the TypeError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have a typo between the `main` method and the other one.

In `main`, you correctly have `element_specification` in the `for`

```
for index, element_specification in enumerate(elements_specification)
```

But in the other method you have `elements_specification` in the `for`

```
for index, elements_specification in enumerate(elements_specification)
```

Which just so happens to be the name of the parameter for that method, so you're reassigning that parameter in your list-comprehension

---

Try this instead

```
lists = [list(list_generated) for index, element in enumerate(elements_specification) for list_generated in itertools.product(*elements_specification[:index + 1])]
return lists
```

Or since you don't even need the `element` from the `enumerate`, just use `range`.

```
lists = [list(list_generated) for index in range(len(elements_specification)) for list_generated in itertools.product(*elements_specification[:index + 1])]
return lists
```